# React useQuery pass data to child component without rerender

Tags: reactjs, graphql, use-effect, use-state

I am new to react, hooks and gql, and got this problem - every time the query runs I got "Loading..." and the rerender of the map component(the map disappears and then appears with the new data). Is there a way to pass it directly to the map without MapBox component rerender and the "Loading..." sign? I think I can put the gql to the MapBox component and run the query from there, but if it possible to do like I described? Thanks

**PS:** every time I click Zoom button, the MapProvider updates the query and prints Loading and rerender the map MapBox component. I want to pass the data from query   somehow to MapBox comp and do not rerender the MapBox component

```
import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import MapBox from "./map";

const MAP_QUERY = gql`
  query MapQuery($position: [[Float]]!, $zoom: Float!) {
    lines: linesByPosition(position: $position, zoom: $zoom) {
     return some lines geojson
    }
  }
`;
const MapProvider = () => {

  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(5);
  const [position, setPosition] = useState([
    [47.61003115514454, 18.991722981667806],
    [47.60679062928742, 19.263634602761556],
    
  ])
  console.log('position', position);
  const { loading, error, data, refetch } = useQuery(MAP_QUERY, {
    variables: {
      zoom: 12, position: [
        [47.61003115514454, 18.991722981667806],
        [47.60679062928742, 19.263634602761556],
      ]
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('REFETCH !!! zoom, positioin', zoom, position);
    refetch({ zoom, position });
  }, [zoom, position]);

  
  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <div>Error: {error.message}</div >;
  const { lines } = data;

  return (<>
    <MapBox geojson={{ lines }} zoom={zoom} />
    <button onClick={
      () => setZoom(zoom + 1)
    }>Zoom</button>
  </>)
}

export default MapProvider;
```

Comment: Do you want after first query loaded it shows and never see the loading right ?

Comment: @b3hr4d yes, I want to load the data and pass it to the MapBox component, without seeing loading every time I update the MapProvider query clicking on Zoom button.

Answer (score 0):

Just Check if data available and show loading :

```
  if (!data && loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (!data && error) return <div>Error: {error.message}</div >;
```

But best way to do that should be making an absolute loading on screen for better user experience or making zoom button disable like this :

```
<button onClick={
  () => setZoom(zoom + 1)
} disable={loading}>Zoom</button>
```